# Alignment and loading issues with bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel which loads 3 slides into view at once. I'm having trouble setting the next and previous backgrounds to white, instead of having the gradient. Also need to figure out alignment when using in a responsive design so that the slides only show one at a time when at mobile size for iPhone/Android, as well as hiding the previous button if at the beginning of the slideshow.

**HTML**

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="review">
                    <p lang="en" dir="ltr">Model S can take you anywhere, come and test drive <a href="http://t.co/NTad8VVhGB">http://t.co/NTad8VVhGB</a>  <a href="http://t.co/xWlvrnDZMG">pic.twitter.com/xWlvrnDZMG</a>

                    </p>&mdash; Tesla Motors (@TeslaMotors) <a href="https://twitter.com/TeslaMotors/status/652149926000889856">October 8, 2015</a>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="review">
                     <h4>Review Title here</h4>

                    <p>by reviewer</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Content of review here. Content of review here. Content of review here.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Controls --> <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 10000
})

$('.carousel .item').each(function () {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    if (next.next().length > 0) {
        next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    } else {
        $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

**CSS**

```
    .review {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    min-height: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    */
}
.carousel-inner .active.left {
    left: -33%;
}
.carousel-inner .active.right {
    left: 33%;
}
.carousel-inner .next {
    left: 33%
}
.carousel-inner .prev {
    left: -33%
}
.carousel-control.left {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 0 35px -2px #888;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 35px -2px #888;
    height: 200px;
}
.carousel-control.right {
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0 35px -2px #888;
    box-shadow: -10px 0 35px -2px #888;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/cwn55ebo/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

OK, After having a look at the Fiddle, I think I may have guessed the problem,

The one which is active is actually an `<iframe>`, while the one which seems to "*not work*" is actually a copied html `DOM`, so it wont behave exactly as the iframe, since a lot changes(CSS, CSS rule priorities, etc) when some foreign `DOM` is loaded(copy pasted) inside the local `DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your jquery, your css and try to repeat the html for each block; them you can hide some blocks at mobile sizes. This is just an idea.